# Какая разница между челночной сортировкой и сортировкой вставками

Tags: сортировка, любой-язык

На одних сайтах говорят, что челночная сортировка - это то же самое, что и шейкерная, а на других сайтах показывают, как работает челночная сортировка, и по принципу работы это похоже на сортировку вставками.
Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, в чем разница и, если можно, дайте пример, где эта разница хорошо видна.

Answer (score 1):

Если у нас есть массив элементов `a` и нам нужно переставить элемент `a[i]` влево в позицию `j` (`j < i`), то сделать это можно двумя способами:

- Способ 1. Сохранить значение `a[i]` в сторонке. Сдвинуть все элементы с индексами `[i, j)` вправо на один шаг, после чего записать исходное значение `a[i]` в "освободившуюся" ячейку `a[i]`.
- Способ 2. Обменять местами элементы `a[i]` и `a[i - 1]`. Затем обменять местами элементы `a[i - 1]` и `a[i - 2]`. И т.д. и т.п. пока мы не обменяем пару `a[j+1]` и `a[j]`. Несложно видеть, что результат такой манипуляции совпадает с вариантом 1.

Сортировка вставками сначала выполняет просмотр левой части массива для того, чтобы найти правильное место `j` для очередного элемента `a[i]`. После этого при помощи метода 1 элемент `a[i]` помещается на правильное место `j`.

Челночная сортировка сразу же начинает выполнять манипуляции метода 2, *на лету* проверяя, не добрался ли уже элемент `a[i]` до своего правильного места в левой части массива.

Единственной более-менее осязаемой разницей между сортировкой вставками и челночной сортировкой является то, то первая *сначала* выполняет проход по левой части массива для поиска места вставки, а *затем* выполняет перемещение нового элемента (что фактически выливается в еще дин проход по левой части массива).

А челночной сортировка *объединяет* и поиск места вставки, и собственно перемещение элементов в единый проход по левой части массива.

---

При желании, вы можете реализовать сортировку вставками, но для перемещения элемента на новое место использовать именно метод 2. В такой ситуации единственным отличием между этими сортировками будет лишь то, что сортировка вставками ищет правильное место для элемента *заранее* (перед выполнением метода 2), а челночной сортировка ищет правильное место для элемента *на лету* (в процессе выполнения метода 2).